# how to auto wrap in path string in latex

Tags: urls, strings, seqsplit

I am write path in latex like this:

```
/data/docker/nginx/volume/conf/conf/conf.d/cert/example.com
```

but the string is too long for compile to pdf, compiled result like this:

[image]

how to handle the path correctly and make it auto wrap?

Comment: Does your document load the `url`, `xurl`, and/or `hyperref` packages? Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting an image it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two straightforward methods that will achieve your formatting objective:

- load the `url` (or `xurl`) package and encase the path string in a `\path` directive. The path string will be rendered in the monospaced text font by default.
- load the `seqsplit` package and encase the path string in a `\seqsplit` directive. The path string will be rendered in the default text font; add `\texttt` or `\ttfamily` directives if you prefer using the monospaced font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url} % or: \usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\begin{document}

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\path{/data/docker/nginx/volume/conf/conf/conf.d/cert/example.com}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 

\bigskip
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
{\ttfamily\seqsplit{/data/docker/nginx/volume/conf/conf/conf.d/cert/example.com}}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there any common way to handle the auto wrap? I am facing a string like this: `"js-wheel": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git"` @Mico

Comment: @Dolphin - Are you asking if there's a way for LaTeX to decide automatically, on its own, whether a given string is elegible for auto-wrapping? I'm not aware of any kind of ready-made functionality. How difficult, though, is it to scan the document for URL strings and to encase them in `\url` wrappers?

Comment: I tried using this solution in the case of using an \href with a long \url but I couldn't get pdflatex to compile on overleaf. Any ideas on this?